# How to update a piece of php code like query with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have this piece of php code :

```
<?php
$food = 100;

$food  $food - 10;
?>
```

and I need to update it so it displays the food variable on the web page immediately  without reloading the whole page

This would be the javascript code:

```
var food = 100;

var food = food - 10;

$("div").html(food);
```

Comment: Your Javascript can't touch your PHP because one runs on the client and one runs on the server. Can you clarify your question please?

Comment: PHP runs on the server so you need to contact the server to get it to do anything - you can't just change parts of the page on the fly unless you're using something like JavaScript/Ajax to contact the server and parse the response.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to set the initial variable on page load you could insert it into your JavaScript like so

```
var food = <?=$food?>
```

This will then allow you to manipulate the value without reloading the page.

Comment: Still processing the data with JavaScript but yeah, if the initial data is coming from PHP this is an option.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language so cannot output data like you want with out refreshing. Javascript can do this because it is client side.